# How to make the second value optional on v-autocomplete(vuejs & vuetify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a v-autocomplete component on my template and I would like display data via item-text. The first value `${item.name}` is will always be rendered but the second value `${item.faculty.name}` comes from a nested relationship and I want to make it optional( if exist then display and if it null then display nothing). How can achieve it.

```
        <v-autocomplete
              v-model="form.classroom"
              :items="classrooms"
              :item-text="item => `${item.name} - ${item.faculty.name}`"
              item-value="id"
              :label="$t('GENERAL.ALL.CLASS_ROOM')"
              hide-selected
              clearable
              prepend-icon="mdi-chair-school"
              :error-messages="serverValidation.getMessage('classroom')"
           ></v-autocomplete>
```

The first value is displaying without problem.

Comment: use a `computed` value, it makes it easier to deal with if you put that logic into your js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ternary operator `condition?option1:option2` :

```
  :item-text="item => item.faculty?`${item.name} - ${item.faculty.name}`:item.name"
```

or

```
:item-text="item => `${item.name} ${item.faculty?' - '+item.faculty.name:''}`"
```

Comment: Worked like a champ sir. Thanks a lot